# GMail не публикует сообщений в Google Cloud Pub/Sub

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud, google-cloud-messages

Сделал скрипт на Google App Script. Он получает уведомление о новой почте через Google Cloud Pub/Sub и разбирает новое письмо. Данные из письма складывает в табличку. Использую бесплатный аккаунт. Сегодня заметил, что перестали приходить оповещения. По мониторингу видно, что сообщения от Google Cloud Pub/Sub не приходят.

Кто с подобным сталкивался? Где можно посмотреть свои бесплатные лимиты? И подскажите, откуда начать копать, чтобы понять в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно читать документацию. Оказывается время подписки ограничено неделей и ее нужно обновлять. Так что сделал тригер что бы срабатывал раз в неделю.